# Select and add column values from another dataframe based on if the index exists in both

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, let's call them `A` and `B`, with the same indexes (person IDs), but some IDs might be in A and not B, and vice versa. Additionally, the IDs are Non-Unique in `B`, while unique in dataframe `A`, so I want to

I want to check `B` to see if there exists certain IDs, then add a column of the max B-Label into A, for that specific ID.

I tried writing the function below as an argument to the pandas .apply() function.

```
def add_labels_to_dataframe(train_df,
                        id_col_name='person_id',
                        label_name="max_progress",
                        label_filepath=LABELS_SRC_FILE,
                        default_value=-1,
                        save=True):
"""
Add labels column to train_df

:param train_df: (DataFrame)
    the training dataframe that needs labels
:param id_col_name: (str)
    name of the ID column to use
:param label_name: (str)
    the column name of the label to use (score/progress/is_X/etc)
:param label_filepath: (str)
    filepath with IDs and associated labels
:param default_value: (int, or anything)
    The default label to give when a person_id has no associated label
:return: (DataFrame)
    updated dataframe with labels
"""
labels_df = pd.read_csv(label_filepath)

def get_max_score(row):
    """
    DataFrame function to select max score when multiple exist per ID

    :param row: (DataFrame)
        A single row of the dataframe being modified
    :return: (int)
        returns elements of a Series that becomes a new column of the DataFrame
    """
    # if person_id is in labels, then get max of labels
    pdb.set_trace()
    pid_labels_df = labels_df[row[id_col_name].isin(labels_df[id_col_name])]

    if not pid_labels_df.empty and not pd.isnull(pid_labels_df[label_name].max()):
        return 1 + pid_labels_df[label_name].max()

    return default_value


train_df[label_name] = train_df.apply(get_max_score, axis=1)

if save:
    train_df.to_csv(LABELED_TRAIN_DF_PATH)

return train_df
```

> ValueError: ('Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects', 'occurred at index 0')

I know I could just convert both dataframe indexes into Python lists, check if value exists, then create a new DataFrame mapping old rows to either labeled values or some default -1, but I'm trying to do this all within Pandas, in order to utilize the vectorization.

Can someone help me figure out a concise way to use only dataframe operations instead of casting to Python lists here?

Comment: Sorry, ironically StackOverflow indentation sucks, and I can only toggle 1-level deep indents. get_max_score() is within the add_labels_to_dataframe() function, so it receives variables outside of its function scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think* you're going to be able to do this with a [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df[label_name] = df.groupby("person_id").transform("max")
```

* It's a little hard to read precisely what your code is attempting to do...